# The Grisbi personal finance program is unable to complete a reconciliation

Tags: linux

I have been running Grisbi 1.2.2 on Linux Mint since 2020 (and before that ran an earlier version for several years). I have found it an effective and satisfying program, and have often recommended it.

I reconcile my account about once a week. Today, when I was done, on hitting 'Validate' a message appeared saying "Reconciliation can't be completed, invalid date".
[image]

I saved and closed and re-opened the program without effect, and changed the date format, also without result.
Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot answer this particular question but I have done hundreds of bank reconciliations (Windows and QuickBooks). Failure to complete a bank or account reconciliation is normally a problem of incomplete or wrong journal entries. Look for that. Otherwise it would be a softare issue and I cannot comment on your environment.

Comment: There were only five new entries, all of which were same old, same old.

Comment: There appears then to be a software issue.  Contact Grisbi Support.

Comment: Another thing to do is to get a 2 week old back up, re-enter transactions to bring up to date, and then re-reconcile.

Comment: The problem seems to have solved itself ... which is nice, but still leaves me wondering.
I suspect some sort of internal conflict over the date; all the transactions I wanted to reconcile were the same date as the date of the reconciliation, and perhaps the program thought I was trying to do a reconciliation *before* the transactions had occurred? I'll start a log in case the problem repeats.